# Measure of the set of periodic points of a measure preserving map

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems

Given a continuous (Lebesgue) measure preserving map $T$ from a compact convex region to itself that has an aperiodic point (i.e. a point $p$ such that $p \ne T^n(p)$ for any $n$), does the set of aperiodic points necessarily have positive measure?

It can be arbitrarily small as can be seen by taking a rubber disk of radius 1 and gluing the disk of radius $1-\epsilon$ having the same center and turning the outer ring by a small irrational amount (so we are deforming only a small annulus), but can it be zero?

Comment: I was wondering if you intended that the map be invertible, or whether you didn't care about that.

Comment: In the specific case I was looking at the maps are invertible.  If that restriction makes the problem tractable, by all means use it.

Comment: I was actually trying to put together a counterexample which wasn't invertible, but it ran into severe difficulty. I am thinking about it though. It seems very likely that the measure is always positive atm, but I'll let you know if I can prove it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be zero. Take your region for instance to be $D=[0,1]\cup\{1+\frac1n\,:\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Define $T(x)=x$ for $x\in[0,1]$ and $T(1+\frac1n)=1+\frac1{n+1}$. Then clearly $T$ is continuous and measure preserving, and the set of aperiodic points is $\{1+\frac1n\,:\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ which has measure zero. I imagine the answer would be different if you also assumed $D$ is connected, but I haven't given that much thought.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming that $D$ was connected (in fact the case that I am interested in has $D$ convex. I have edited the question (which now feels like cheating).

Comment: In that case, is your example continuous?

Comment: The region is convex, therefore connected, and the map is definitely continuous (piecewise linear for now, but the general continuous case is of interest).

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what map you mean. I'm assuming we have $T(x)=x$ if $|x|\le1-\epsilon$, $T(x)=e^{i\theta}x$ if $1-\epsilon<|x|\le1$ where $\theta$ is irrational. This map is certainly not continuous. If $|x|=1-\epsilon$, then take sequences $(x_n),(y_n)$ with $|x_n|<1-\epsilon<|y_n|$ and $x_n,y_n\to x$. Then $Tx_n\to x$ but $Ty_n\to e^{i\theta}x$.

Comment: Although I guess you can modify it slightly to get a continuous function. Let $\phi$ be a smooth function on the unit disk $D$ with $\phi(x)=0$ for $|x|\le1-\epsilon$ and $\phi(x)>0$ otherwise. Define $T(x)=e^{i\phi(x)}x$. Then $T$ is continuous and measure preserving, and $x$ aperiodic implies $|x|>1-\epsilon$. The set $\{x\in D\,:\,\phi(x)\notin\mathbb{Q}\}$ also certainly has positive measure.

Comment: That is what I meant by a rubber sheet, you are just pulling the outer ring, and the annulus stretches.

Comment: One observation:  About any such aperiodic point $p$, for any positive integer $N$ there is a positive value $\epsilon_N$ such that all points within an $\epsilon_N$ radius of $p$ have period at least $N$.  In particular, any sequence of points that converges to $p$ must have periods that diverge to infinity.  This just uses continuity of $T$.

Comment: Similarly, if $X_k$ is the set of all points that have period $k$, then $X_k$ is a closed (and hence measurable) set.

Comment: It follows that $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k$ is measurable, and so its complement, being the set of all aperiodic points, is a measurable set.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to define the compact convex region itself to have zero measure, such as a 2-d square in 3-space.  For example, consider the following set $\mathcal{X}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, which is a compact and convex set with measure zero:

$$ \mathcal{X} = \{(x,y,0) : x \in [0,1], y \in [0,1]\} $$

Define $T(x,y,0) = (x^2,y,0)$. Then the point $(1/2,0,0)$ is aperiodic, and the set of all aperiodic points trivially has measure zero.

---

Of course, this example breaks the spirit of your question.  I think you are looking for a compact, convex set $\mathcal{X} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ that itself has positive measure.  Just a few observations about that:

1) Define $\mathcal{A}_k = \{x \in \mathcal{X} : T^{(k)}(x)=x\}$. Then $\mathcal{A}_k$ is closed (and hence measurable).

Proof: Let $x$ be a limit point of $\mathcal{A}_k$ and let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be an infinite sequence of points in $\mathcal{A}_k$ that converges to $x$. Then $T^{(k)}(x_n)=x_n$ for all $n$.  Taking a limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ and using continuity of $T^{(k)}$ gives $T^{(k)}(x) = x$, so $x \in \mathcal{A}_k$. So $\mathcal{A}_k$ is closed (and hence measurable).

2) The set $\cup_{k=1}^{K}\mathcal{A}_k$ is closed and measurable, its limiting set  $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{A}_k$ is measurable, and so the set of all aperiodic points is measurable.

Proof:  The finite union of closed sets is closed (and hence measurable).  The limit of an increasing sequence of measurable sets is measurable.  The set of all aperiodic points is the complement of $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{A}_k$, and the complement of a measurable set is measurable.

3) If $x$ is an aperiodic point in $\mathcal{X}$ and if $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an infinite sequence of points in $\mathcal{X}$ that converges to $x$, then the smallest period of $x_n$ diverges to infinity as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Proof:  Suppose there is a positive integer $N$ such that $x_n$ has smallest period less than or equal to $N$ for an infinite number of indices $n$.  Then there is an integer $k\leq N$ such that $T^{(k)}(x_{n[i]})=x_{n[i]}$ for an infinite subsequence $x_{n[i]}$.  Taking a limit as $i\rightarrow\infty$ gives $T^{(k)}(x)=x$, contradicting the fact that $x$ is an aperiodic point.